# Map from first table to the other table and insert fieldname and value using laravel5

Tags: php, laravel

Map from first table to the other table and insert fieldname and value using laravel5

I want to map the value from one table to input field

if submitted input field match with user table do nothing if differents found updated into the profile table with fieldname into the profile column (column) that updated and value
     e.g if in user table first_name having 'jimmy' and current field 'first_name'  having 'james' updated james in new table with fieldname in the column 'first_name' gets updated and value 'james' in other column along with id

user table having the same field

profile table foreign column name u_id

```
'first_name' => $input['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $input['last_name'],
    'gender'    => $input['gender'],
    'dob'    => $input['dob'],
    'language'  => $input['language'],
    'location'  => $input['location'],
    'email'     => $input['email'],
    'phone'     => $input['phone'],
```